# Boost_fields per class in Sunspot

Tags: boost, solr, sunspot

So in Sunspot, it is possible to do this:

```
QUERY_DOCUMENT_BOOST_OPTIONS = {
  :user => 2,
  :product => 1,
}

fulltext query do
  [User, Product].each do |m|
    boost(QUERY_DOCUMENT_BOOST_OPTIONS[m.name.underscore.to_sym]) { with(:class, m) }
  end
end
```

Is it also possible to do something like this for boosting fields? So that a field would be boosted only if it was in a document of a certain class.

Is it possible to achieve something like this? Is it even possible in solr directly? This does not work, of course, because boost_fields doesn't take a block:

```
QUERY_FIELD_BOOST_OPTIONS[m.name.underscore.to_sym].each do |field, boost|
  boost_fields(field => boost) { with(:class, m) }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not found a direct way to do this, but you can always namespace field names, by using sunspot's :as option.

So a then in a model you would do:

```
searchable do 
  text: title, :as => 'model_title_text'
end
```

And when searching you would do

```
search = Sunspot.search [Model] do
  fulltext query
  adjust_solr_params do |params| 
    params['qf'] += ' model_title_text^10'
  end
end
```